# Converting dv to mpeg

Tags: dvd, ffmpeg

I'm trying to transfer videos from an old tape recorder onto DVDs. I think that I need to use ffmpeg to convert the dv files to mpeg but can't find the right commands to use. Does anybody know what the right commands are or if there is an alternative method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with FFmpeg and DVDauthor. A very *basic* form of the required command lines would be:

**1. Convert to mpg:**

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -target pal-dvd -aspect 16:9 -ac 2 output.mpg
```

This command line can be *embellished* to your taste and also *altered* to fit any form of input file. **Tip:** Perhaps add in a *bitrate* setting for the video: `-b:v 6000k` or even a *quality* setting: `-qscale:v 2` if the output video is at all disappointing.

**Note:** For those in non-'PAL' countries the option would be `-target ntsc-dvd` rather than `-target pal-dvd`.

**2. Create the DVD structure:**

Create the file `$HOME/.config/video_format` and place either PAL or NTSC in the file (depending which is relevant in your country), using your favourite text editor. I use PAL in the following example for the command line to create the DVD structure:

```
dvdauthor -t -o dvd --video=pal -f output.mpg
dvdauthor -T -o dvd
```

**Note:** For those in non-'PAL' countries the option would be `--video=ntsc` rather than `--video=pal`.

**3. Create the iso:**

Use `mkisofs` to then create an iso suitable for burning to DVD:

```
mkisofs -dvd-video -o testing.iso dvd/
```

**4. Burn to DVD:**

Finally you can use K3B or whichever tool you prefer to burn the iso to DVD; perhaps even use the following command line:

```
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr0=testing.iso
```

And then sit back and enjoy your movie :)

**References:**

- [How to make an MPEG2 video file with the highest quality possible using FFMPEG?](https://superuser.com/questions/835871/how-to-make-an-mpeg2-video-file-with-the-highest-quality-possible-using-ffmpeg): Some thoughts on creating a high quality encode with FFmpeg

Comment: Since I live in the US do I need to change everything to NTSC? In the first step do I do `ntsc-dvd` instead of `pal-dvd`?

Comment: @kingofrubik I believe that this would be the case although I have never run the ntsc options, no ntsc here :)

Comment: Give me a little time and I will test the ntsc syntax...