# How to Make DVD From .mov File?

Tags: video-editor

How do I produce a DVD from a .mov? I shot video using camera that also takes movie shots. I use K3b to burn DVD's and CD's. The file is at /home/xyz/Videos/Lights

Comment: Not sure if this old answer of mine will still be useful: https://askubuntu.com/a/1015032/57576

Answer (score 2):

In order to burn .mov files to DVD, you have to encode the video/audio/subtitles into dvd-compliant mpeg2 format. This can be done with any number of programs, such as ffmpeg, mencoder, or avidemux.

The disk itself has to be "authored". That is, a menu system has to be created for it and everything broken up into the required dvd file structure. Generally, dvdauthor is the underlying program that does most of the work,

However, some programs like *devede* can automate some or all of the steps for you, and can easily create simple-to-intermediate level menus. I recommend devede. To install it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install devede
```

Comment: Installed devede. That works for now. Boy it is a real clusterfuck logging into this place.